# Calculating Variance when there is a random variable in the exponent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance

I'm struggling with calculating $$V(e^U+e^{1-U})\qquad\text{while}\qquad U\sim U(0,1)$$
My problem is that I don't know how to approach exercises where there is a random variable in the exponents.
I tried to play with the expectation and with the definition but i can't advance.
Any clues guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=e^U+e^{1-U}$. Then $\text{Var}(Z)$ is computed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(Z)&=\mathbb{E}(Z^2)-\mathbb{E}(Z)^2\\
&=\int_0^1z^2\mathrm{d}u-\left(\int_0^1z\mathrm{d}u\right)^2\\
&=\int_0^1e^{2u}+2e+e^{2-2u}\mathrm{d}u-\left(\int_0^1e^u+e^{1-u}\mathrm{d}u\right)^2
\end{align*}
Can you compute these integrals?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i have a question for you.
I know that the expectation of a continuous variable is (with $U$ as noted)$$E(x)=\int_0^1xf_x(x)dx$$
So how do you know what is the density function of this $Z$ variable, also i don't see it in the integral.
what am i missing?

Comment: In your example, $\mathbb{E}[g(U)]=\int_0^1g(u)f(u)\mathrm{d}u$, where $f(u)=1$. In the case where $g(u)=e^{u}+e^{1-u}$, you get my result above.

Comment: So tell me if i got it right, $e^u$ is uniformly distributed because $u$ is uniformly distributed so i can conclude that its density function is 1 because the domain is (0,1). And so is for the other function $e^{1-u}$?

Comment: Unfortunately, $e^u$ is not uniformly distributed. If you wanted to determine the probability density function for $e^u$, you have two options (at least): You can compute a cumulative distribution function $\mathbb{P}(e^U\leq u)$ and differentiate the result, or you can use a formula (see https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157 ).